# Why can not I connect to Webmin on my AWS centOS server?

Tags: centos, amazon-web-services, centos-7, webmin

I have a centOS server on AWS and I can not connect to Webmin. I followed the installation steps that (shows this page), but when I click on the link that is generated after completing the installation of Webmin, the following error appears: This website can not be accessed The IP address of the server xxxxxxxxxxx could not be found. DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN I have read other responses: ()

I have searched for a solution by Google for three days without success. On the server I have enabled ports 10000, 22, 21, 20 I do not know what else I can do or where to go. I may not show you enough details of my problem so you can help me, but it's the first time on this site that I read the rules. If I have to add more details, please tell me what I can do so they can help me. I also use a translator to ask the question, which can cause errors. Can you help me connect Webmin to my server? Thank you